# adding effect in appended element

Tags: jquery, fadeout, appendchild

[This is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/hfof316a/2/). There is a list group. By clicking "Add" button a popup will come at where there is a "Create" button. After clicking on the "Create" button, sample list item will be added before the "Add" button in the list group.

Now, I want some effect so that user can understand at where the created list-item has been added. So, I'm thinking adding a different color in the appended element and disappearing the different color smoothly like `fadeOut()`. That's why, at the time of appending, I've added a new class named .temp and styled it. so, after adding the "Created List", it looks different. Now, how can I remove the `.temp` class instantly (within 2/3 second maybe) and smoothly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing it after 2/3 of a second is easy: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/hfof316a/3/

```
$('body').on('click', '.create-list', function () {
    var $element = $('<a href="#" class="list-group-item temp" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#listPopup"> Created List <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle pull-right remove"></span> </a>');
    $('.add').before($element);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $element.removeClass("temp");
    }, 666);
});
```

You also need to set your transition on the item (not with the temp):

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/hfof316a/6/

Comment: at where should I use CSS transition?. I've already used it in .temp class.

Comment: @user1896653: Sorted... the transition needs to be applied to the non `.temp` item in the CSS.

Comment: There is no special reason!! Actually, you answered it first. But, that was not 100% solution (i.e: transition issue). "Before Your Editing", a new answer had come which provide the 100% solution. That's why, I chose that answer.

Comment: You're right. You edited it at first before the new answer. But, unfortunately, I didn't notice that. Today, after your concentration, I've noticed that. But, I felt embarrassed to remove "Accepted" answer from other as that is correct too and that person might be feel sad/angry for that. That's why, I didn't understand what should I do. But, on the other hand, you wasn't happy too as you deserved it at first. That was my mistake not to notice the edited time. That's why, I've accepted your answer just now. Sorry for the mistake and thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `temp` class after some time:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(".temp:first").removeClass("temp");
}, 1000);
```

And add transition to `list-group-item` class not to `temp` class(because it gets removed after some time).

```
.list-group-item {
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

[**See updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/hfof316a/4/)